# How to load dynamically a new page from dynamically loaded html?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, fetch, client-server

I currently have a problem where I have a pictures page of my webpage which dynamically uploads pictures which the user can upload. Each of the picture cards has a button which can be clicked on to show a new page containing comments about that specific picture. Both the comment and picture info is stored on a server in an array. I'm not sure how to make the button on each picture card generate a new page without coding a new HTML page as its a single page app. Also, how would I go about passing the value of the title of the pic into the new page so that I can filter the comments to only include those about the specific picture?I already have get and post requests which return all the pics and comments from the server.
**server.js**

```
function loadpics() {
    document.getElementById('insertpics').innerHTML='' 
    fetch ('http://127.0.0.1:8090/pics',{
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type":"application/json"
        }
     })
    .then((res) => { return res.json(); })
    .then(pics => {
        for (let pic of pics){
            const y= `
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
            <img class="card-img-top" src=${pic.picurl} alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
              <h5 class="card-title">${pic.username}</h5>
              <p class="card-text">${pic.nameofpic}</p>
            <a  class="btn btn-info" href="#" >View Comments on this picture</a>
            </div>
          </div>
            `;

            document.getElementById('insertpics').innerHTML+=y;
        }
    })
};
loadpics();
```

As you can see I have a button at the end of the card but have no idea how to make it generate a blank page with just the comments linked to that photo on. The picture array has this structure [{"username":"username","picname":"nameofpic","pic":"pic.png"}] and the comment array has this structure [{"username":"username","picname":"nameofpic","comment":"comment"}]. Any help would be greatly appreciated ! edit: someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page just of the single pic and comments.
Add the url in "a" tag. e.g. [http://127.0.0.1:8090/viewPic/{id}](http://127.0.0.1:8090/viewPic/%7Bid%7D)

Comment: is there any way you could explain how I would go about doing this or give further details? I'm sorry I'm very new to js and servers

Comment: How would I create the page whilst also ensuring I have a single page app style and How would I populate the page with the specific comments using fetch ?

Comment: The above ans was not for single page application. For SPA, use JavaScript and CSS to change the style of the cards. Eg:You could have a "active" CSS class, which changes the card CSS properties to cover the will screen etc, then with the help of js add and remove the CSS class on the selected element.

Comment: is there any chance you could show me an example of how I would load this css and js in when the button is pressed ? I'm sorry Im still very confused.